# .htaccess mod-rewrite: Modify working RewriteRule to catch any subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following working RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}#%{HTTP_HOST} ^IG([^&#]+)#(?:www\.)?([^.]+)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mysite.de/link/ig/%2/%1? [L,NE,R=302]
```

**I would like to modify the RewriteRule to catch any subdomain not just `www`.**

I honestly don't understand this part `(?:www\.)?`. The second `?` says that everything before could occur 0 - any times. But I don't understand the first question mark in combination with the colon.

I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}#%{HTTP_HOST} ^IG([^&#]+)#(.+\.)?([^.]+)\. [NC]
```

and this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}#%{HTTP_HOST} ^IG([^&#]+)#(?:.+\.)?([^.]+)\. [NC]
```

Both do not work.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong, this does work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}#%{HTTP_HOST} ^IG([^&#]+)#(?:.+\.)?([^.]+)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mysite.de/link/ig/%2/%1? [L,NE,R=302]
```

Could anyone explain this part `(?:www\.)?` anyway please?

Comment: Do you know https://regex101.com? That can do a lot of the explaining already - https://regex101.com/r/kDfE67/1/ `(?:` starts a non-capturing group, meaning even if this part was matched, it will not create a back reference.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you very much!